# Is it possible to get the NUnit TestContext MethodName from within an IEnumerable method?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, nunit, ienumerable

I am using NUnits `IEnumerable` to try and return test data by method name in a Nunit `SetUpFixture` test base class (see bottom of class):

```
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestBase
    {
        private readonly BrowserFactory _factory = new BrowserFactory();
        protected IWebDriver Driver;

        private static ExtentReports _extent;
        private static string _projectPath;
        protected ExtentTest _test;
        private static TestContext testContext;
  
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            InitializeReport();
            _test = _extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
            Driver = _factory.Init(Config.Browser);
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            string testClassName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;
            var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace) ? "" : string.Format("{0}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
            Status logstatus;

            switch (status)
            {
                case TestStatus.Failed:
                    logstatus = Status.Fail;
                    Console.WriteLine("Test status is Fail");
                    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                    String fileName = "Screenshot_" + time.ToString("h_mm_ss") + ".png";
                    String screenShotPath = Capture(Driver, fileName);
                    _test.Log(Status.Fail, "Fail");
                    _test.Log(Status.Fail, "Snapshot below: " + _test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath("Screenshots\\" + fileName));
                    break;

                case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                    logstatus = Status.Warning;
                    break;

                case TestStatus.Skipped:
                    logstatus = Status.Skip;
                    break;

                default:
                    logstatus = Status.Pass;
                    Console.WriteLine("Test status is Pass");
                    break;
            }

            _test.Log(logstatus, "Test " + " - " + testMethodName + " Ended with a status of " + logstatus + stacktrace);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void OneTimeTearDown()
        {
            CloseBrowser();     
            _extent.Flush();
        }

        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            Driver?.Close();
            Driver?.Quit();
            Driver?.Dispose();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<JObject> GetTestData()
        {
            string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;

            JObject[] testDataReturned = GetDataByMethod(testMethodName);

            for (int i = 0; i < testDataReturned.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return testDataReturned[i];
            }
        }

        public static JObject[] GetDataByMethod(string testMethodName)
        {
            return JsonUtils.FetchData(testMethodName);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I run this code, the string `testMethodName` within the `IEnumerable` method `GetTestData()` has a value of `AdhocTestMethod`, instead of the actual test method string `LoginTest_E2E`.

I am able to fetch TestContext data such as MethodName just fine within my `OneTimeSetUp()` and `TearDown()` (see above), but cannot get the method name returned within the `IEnumerable`.

The test case I am using the `IEnumerable` as follows:

```
        [Test, TestCaseSource("GetTestData")]
        public void LoginTest_E2E(JObject testData)
        {  
            string loginId = testData["loginId"].Value<string>();
            string password = testData["password"].Value<string>();
            string useCase = testData["useCase"].Value<string>();  
        }
```

For reference, the .json data file I am using in the test is:

```
{
  "LoginTest_E2E": [
    {
      "loginId": "testuser1",
      "password": "password1",
      "useCase": "verify for user 1"
    },
    {
      "loginId": "tesetuser2",
      "password": "password2",
      "useCase": "verify for user 2"
    }
  ]
```

Does anyone know why I am unable to get the string value for `testMethodName` within the `IEnumerable` method?

Here is the method in question again:

```
public static IEnumerable<JObject> GetTestData()
{
    string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName;

    JObject[] testDataReturned = GetDataByMethod(testMethodName);

    for (int i = 0; i < testDataReturned.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return testDataReturned[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear from the question where your example code for GetTestData is located in the test and how it is called. Please show code that starts from some established point in your tests, like a TestFixture or SetUpFixture.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie. I updated my question with more details. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

With the added info, it becomes clear that you have two fundamental problems here.

#### First Problem

You are using your `TestBase` class for two purposes: as a `SetUpFixture` and as a base class for one or more `TestFixture` classes. This is not how a `SetUpFixture` is expected to be used. This becomes clear if you analyze what happens in such a situation.

Let's say that you have a class, `SomeFixture`, containing tests, in the same namespace as `TestBase`. When you run your tests, the following methods are executed...

1. `TestBase.OneTimeSetUp` (as part of the SetUpFixture)
2. `TestBase.OneTimeSetUp` (a second time, as the base class of Somefixture)
3. `SomeFixture.OneTimeSetup` (if it has one)
4. `SomeFixture.OneTimeTearDown` (ditto)
5. `TestBase.OneTimeTearDown` (as the base class)
6. `TestBase.OneTimeTearDown` (as the SetUpFixture)

(Of course, between steps 3 and 4, each of your methods would run, preceded by any `SetUp` and followed by any `TearDown`.)

The above is bad news because the `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` methods are run twice, in two different contexts: In one of them, the test name is `TestBase` and in the other it's `SetUpFixture`. (Remember, NUnit fixtures are considered to be "tests" and have their own context)

**Conclusion:** For proper use of SetUpFixture as designed, it should **not** be a base class for your TestFixtures. C# lets you do that, of course, because it knows nothing about the meaning of the NUnit attributes. NUnit doesn't forbid it, frankly, because none of us ever thought of using it that way when the feature was being designed. If we had, some sort of check could have been made and an error issued.

[Here's an odd thing. I had not seen this problem arise for all the years that `SetUpFixture` has existed. But I've seen it three times in the past few months. I wonder if there's some article or example out there showing this pattern of inheriting from a `SetUpFixture`.]

#### Second Problem

This is the one that causes your data to be unavailable.

Your test case source is located in the base class. That's OK, assuming you want all fixtures, which derive from the base, to use the same data. The problem here is that you are trying to use the `TestContext` of the individual test method in generating the data.

But that context is only created after the tests is defined and it's the test case source that is used to create the tests. The individual tests have a context *only after they start to execute*!

There remains to explain the odd business of "AdHocTestMethod"...

Once upon a time, we threw an exception if you tried to access the `TestContext` when it had not yet been created for a test. This broke certain kinds of code, which had worked in NUnit V2 and people complained. So now, when you do this, we create an ad-hoc context on the fly and allow the old behavior (which I'm not going to specify here) to continue to work. Since the context needs a test name, we gave it one: "AdHocTestMethod".

You are (unintentionally) trying to access a `TestContext` before it has been created, so you get that rather odd method. It should probably throw in this situation, but it can't because it would be a breaking change.

**Conclusion:** You can't access the context *of the test method* in your test case source because you are running in the context of the fixture itself and you are running before any test execution begins. Generating tests and data is part of discovery, not execution.